# Rails 3 routing help, how can I use resources for this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My account_controller has the following actions:

/accounts/index
/accounts/show/12321
/accounts/edit/234234

I have this so far in my routes file:

```
get "accounts/index"  
match "accounts/show/:id" => "accounts#show"
```

Can I use resources instead somehow?

Currently my `accounts#index` routes doesn't work if you have a url like:

```
/accounts/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `resources` would change your URL structure:

- /accounts/index would become /accounts
- /accounts/show/:id would become /accounts/:id
- /accounts/edit/:id would become /accounts/:id/edit

But the action names in the controller would stay the same.

If you don't mind losing the old URLs, or if you could set up redirects from the old URLs to the new ones, then using `resources` would result in a more conventional, RESTful design, so it's "better" by that standard.